# Solve integral equation by converting to differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

One has the following integral equation:

$$y(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}+\int_{0}^{x}\sin(x-t)y(t)dt$$

How can I solve this integral equation by converting it to a differential equation?

Comment: It might be helpful to know how to differentiate an integral with respect to a variable both in the limit and in the integrand, i.e.
$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int\limits_{0}^{x}{f(x,y)\text{ d}y}\right) = f(x,x) + \int\limits_{0}^{x}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)\text{ d}y}. $

Comment: I would be tempted to use some sort of transformation on this thing that takes advantage of the fact that the integral is a convolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g(x)=\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$.  Then, we have

$$y(x)=g(x)+\int_0^x \sin(x-t)y(t)dt \tag 1$$

Differentiating both sides of $(1)$ yields

$$y'(x)=g'(x)+\int_0^x \cos(x-t)y(t)dt \tag 2$$

Differentiating both sides of $(2)$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
y''(x)&=g''(x)+y(x)-\int_0^x \sin(x-t)y(t)dt \tag 3\\\\
&=g''(x)+g(x) \tag 4
\end{align}$$

where we used $(1)$ $(3)$ to arrive at $(4)$.  Thus, upon integrating both sides of $(4)$ we find

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{y(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}+x\arctan(x)-\frac12 \log(x^2+1)} \tag 5$$

where we used $y(0)=1$ and $y'(0)=0$ as provided by $(1)$ and $(2)$ to obtain $(5)$.

Comment: Thanks you so much man but if I have like this integral equation $$y(x)=e^{-x}cos(x)-\int_{0}^{x}e^{-x+t}cos(x) y(t)dt$$ how can I solve it by converting it to a differential equation

Comment: @MhmdDiyene You're welcome!  My pleasure.  It would take more analysis than the comment box permits to write that analysis of the integral equation $$y(x)=e^{−x} cos(x)−\int_o^x e^{−x+t} cos(x)y(t)dt $$Can you post this as a question on MSE?  I'd be happy to have a look at it.

Comment: Okay , and I wish if you answer me

Comment: @MhmdDiyene I will be happy to answer.  Just let me know where and when you've posted the question.  OK?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1394663/how-can-i-solve-this-integral-equation-by-converting-it-to-a-differential-equati/1394677#1394677

Comment: Who just gave this a down vote for no apparent reason?  If you're going to down vote, please leave a comment. Preferably comment first.

Answer (score 0):

if we assign the second part on the right side as $I$ we can quickly apply 
[Differentiation of integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) to arrive at $I^{''} = -I $

observing that $I = y(x)-\frac{1}{1+x^2}$  we can reduce the final differential equation to  $y^{''}+y - 1/(1+x^2) -d^2(1/(1+x^2))/dx^2=0 $

now substitute $z = y - 1/(1+x^2)$  .  hence $z^{''} + z = 0 $

Comment: Well, actually $I''=-I+y$

Comment: you are right about that.

Comment: Help me http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1397836/find-the-critical-curves-for-the-following-functional-with-subsidiary-conditions